Can you grant more delegated permissions than a user has direct permissions?
We have a SharePoint site where users can only create and edit files indirectly, via an application that updates the site using Graph API calls using app permissions.
This means that the files are listed as having been created and updated by the app. It would be better if the files were listed as created by the users who created them, which would be possible by using delegated permissions instead of application permissions. However, we do not want to grant permissions to add documents to the site directly, so I am not sure we can give them permissions to add documents only via graph API calls?
Is this possible?

If you want to use delegated permissions, then you will have to give add/edit permissions to the users on your site because delegated permissions on Microsoft Graph API do not give access to users on a site that the user doesn't have direct permissions.
You will get more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-overview?tabs=http
Also, if you don't want to give direct access on the site then you can use Application permissions with Graph API and create one person field in your document library and store that user explicitly who has add/edit the document. Also, keep version enable in the document library so you can track if who all has edited this document. This column will act as default created by/modified by column it's just you will have to update it each time.
